# Convert Gridview Datas to XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview

I Want to sort manually my data in a gridview, moving row with up/down buttons à the right of gridview. But, i mustn't too ask the server ! that's the difficulty.

So I find a solution.

First I bind gridview to my database,
then i want to export gridview datas to two XML files, one static and one as new source to gridview who is going to be sorted, in the aim to compare the twice after sorting, finding the changes and then update only the rows who are changed in the database.
Do you think that is a good idea ?
Have you other idea to do that ?

I've to use an other method, because it is impossible to sort gridview dynamically for my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read your data in a structure that allows sorting. You have several options. One of the easy ones is a DataTable, then use a view to sort the data in any way you like. Use that view to bind to the grid. It takes about 2-3 lines of code. For example, please see: [DataView](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dataview).

The solution with XML is difficult to implement and is probably slower since it involves I/O. Specially in a web application.

Either solutions require that the entire data be grabbed before the sort begins.